# svDialogs not showing popup boxes, creates interactive text in console instead

Tags: r

I am trying to use the svDialogs package to show a popup box with a message. 
When I try to run dlgMessage("Hello Stackoverflow!") in RStudio as an example it will show Hello Stackoverflow! in the console as text but a popup box will not appear. 
If I use RGUI I can see the popup box as expected. How can I see the message boxes when running the code in RStudio?